# Using NetInfo middleware in React Native with Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to test in all components whether the user has connection to the internet.

I could use `NetInfo` in each component, but since I am using `redux`, I thought it could be done easier with a middleware(?).

I have used

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';   

const netInfo = store => next => action => {
  const listener = (isConnected) => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: types.NET_INFO_CHANGED,
      isConnected,
    });
  };

  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', listener);
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(listener);

  return next(action);  
};

const store = createStore(AppReducer, applyMiddleware(netInfo));
```

where `AppReducer` is just `combineReducers(navReducer, netInfoReducer, ...)`.

It does seem to work, but I am really worried if this performs well enough. It seems it is only run once, but I am never removing the listener or anything.

Is this how you normally would do if you want to populate all components with an `isConnected` variable?

Comment: Couldn't this same thing be achieved with a HOC? I would guess that using an HOC would reduce some complexity and as a result ease your mind. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a [Higher-Order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) for this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';

function withNetInfo(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(this.handleChange);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      NetInfo.isConnected. removeEventListener('change', this.handleChange);
    }

    handleChange(isConnected) {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent isConnected={this.state.isConnected} {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}

export default withNetInfo;
```

Then you can wrap whatever component you would like to render:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isConnected } = this.props;

    return(
      <View>
        <Text>
          {`Am I connected? ${isConnected}`}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNetInfo(MyComponent);
```

---

Bonus: if you want to keep the statics methods of your original component (if you have defined some) you should use the package [hoist-non-react-statics](https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics) to copy the non-react specific statics:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';
import hoistStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics';

function withNetInfo(WrappedComponent) {
  class ExtendedComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(this.handleChange)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      NetInfo.isConnected. removeEventListener('change', this.handleChange);
    }

    handleChange(isConnected) {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent isConnected={this.state.isConnected} {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return hoistStatics(ExtendedComponent, WrappedComponent);
}

export default withNetInfo;
```

Comment: It is a good solution, but it only gives `MyComponent` the prop. I want to be able to access the prop in all components in my app.

Comment: You can decorate any components you want with `withNetInfo()`. It gives you even more control.

Comment: But won't it give performance issues if I'm adding event listeners to every single component mount?

Comment: That's what I was unsure. We would need some React master to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a performance issue using middleware to keep "isConnected" in your redux store, but you would want to make sure the listener is only added once. I use https://github.com/michaelcontento/redux-middleware-oneshot to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I considered middleware, too, but was also afraid how to handle the sub/unsub. I've decided to go with adding and removing the listener in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` of my AppContainer class, which holds the rest of the app in my MainNavigator. This class' lifecycle should follow that of the app, and thus make sure to sub/unsub correctly. I am, however, also going to use a redux action to set the status and listen to it in the relevant views to show a 'no connection' banner.